# Trigger based on listboxitem value

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox

I want to set the set the color of the `ListBoxItem` which is from the type of `DummyQuestion` based on the value of the boolean property `Answered`
here is what I did, but it didn't work, and I think I have problem with the Binding Path

```
<ListView>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DummyQuestion}">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Width="45" Height="45">
                <Ellipse.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                        <Style.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BaseGrey}" />
                        </Style.Setters>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger 
                                Binding="{Binding 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, 
                                Path=Answered}" 
                                Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BaseGreen}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger 
                                Binding="{Binding 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, 
                                Path=Marked}" 
                                Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Accent}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Ellipse.Style>
            </Ellipse>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SerialNumber}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
<local:DummyQuestion
    Answered="False"
    ArText="xxxx"
    Marked="False"
    SerialNumber="1"
    Text="xxxx?" />
<local:DummyQuestion
    Answered="True"
    ArText="yyyy"
    Marked="False"
    SerialNumber="2"
    Text="yyyy" />
<local:DummyQuestion
    Answered="False"
    ArText="zzzz"
    Marked="False"
    SerialNumber="3"
    Text="zzzz" />
```

and here is the DummyQuestion Class:

```
public class DummyQuestion
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ArText { get; set; }
    public bool Answered { get; set; }
    public bool Marked { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to add relativesource, Remove the relativesource from the binding expression.